# jQuery and jQuery UI on the same page

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am working on a project that another developer started. They used jQuery UI for some of the effects, and I am not exactly sure how I can use jQuery for my AJAX functions and still have the jQuery UI stuff functional.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the others have said, jQuery UI uses jQuery and thus jQuery is a dependency.  What that also means though, is that it needs to be included ***AFTER*** jQuery for jQuery UI to work.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI is dependent on jQuery, so assuming the jQuery UI widgets/effects are actually working, you can just go ahead and start using the ajax API.

Comment: Ok, it just does not seem to be overriding the form submit function.

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI uses jQuery. In other words, jQuery is a dependency for jQueryUI. You will need to include both javascript files